# IntelliJ colors scheme customization

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I'm trying to personalize colors scheme in an IntelliJ's theme, but i'm having difficulties to find these entities. In particular, I need to find the entity names of the gray lines pointed by red arrows. Can someone tell me how to find and change these colors entities?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Guides | **Hard wrap guide** or/and **Visual guides**.
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | **Matched brace**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | **Tear line**

Answer (score 0):

The right line is called the "Hard wrap guide". I couldn't find settings for the other two.